# Buttons Dont Work While On Iphone 6 plus and Iphone 7 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Inside a XIB file I have several buttons. Each button moves to a different point inside the ScrollView. The buttons only work on iPhone 6 Plus and 7 Plus. There is a button in each phrase below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the view that all the buttons are contained in.

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

The above will allow you to see where the view is located. My guess is that you will find that the buttons that can't be tapped on are not inside the rectangle defined by their parent view. Therefore, they can't receive taps.

To fix, make sure that the view is large enough to contain all of its child views.